# AngularJS SubForm performance during transition

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angular-ui

Sorry this isn't purely a programming question just trying to understand why a fix works.

I'm using angular-ui and building a form. When completing the steps of the form I have a sliding animation that does a transform. It's not necessarily part of the issue as I will generally get 60+ fps during the animation.

However, one part of the form, if the user has multiple subform elements filled out the ajax call, adding them to the dom, etc is too much and their is a lot of jitter.

I've fixed this by applying an ng-if="isLoaded" to the ng-repeated subform elements. And then setting $scope.isLoaded = true when the ajax call completes.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in employmentHistory" ng-if="isLoaded" ng-form="subForm">
```

Could someone explain why this makes the animation so much more performant? I looked through the timeline and it looks like most of the flame graph just dissapeared.

I understand that ng-if doesn't add the element to the DOM so that will help but even though it does it a fraction of a second later it seems to help out immensely.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR the way ng-if works is that elements will not be loaded into the DOM until the conditional evaluates as true (or moreover they're removed from the DOM until the conditional evaluates). You're likely seeing a large performance increase as the size of the DOM is vastly reduced.

Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: So the fraction of a second difference between when the animation is fired and the dom gets loaded helps this much! I'm very surprised and actually quite glad the fix was this easy.